# how to align checkbox.label and input horizontally

Tags: html, css, angular

how to modify the below posted html code to have all of the checkbox, label and the input-container aligned horizontally. the posted code below gives me the alignment as shown in the screen-shot.

**code**:

```
 <div class="modal-body">
            <form #form="ngForm" class="clr-form  clr-form-horizontal" autocomplete="off">
                <clr-toggle-wrapper>
                <input  type="checkbox" clrCheckbox  (change)="toggleSelectPesticide1()"  [(checked)]="pesticide1Selected"/>
                <label >
                    {{ "SITE.GET_LIDAR" | translate }} 
                </label>
                </clr-toggle-wrapper>
                <clr-input-container>
                    <input
                    required
                    maxlength="25" 
                    clrInput
                    type="text"
                    name="name2"
                    [(ngModel)]=iPesticidesDosesPasser.dose1
                    #name2="ngModel"
                />
            </clr-input-container>
            </form>
        </div>
```

**image**:

[image]

**update_1**:

[image]

Comment: Maybe: `form {display: flex}` ?

Comment: @ArRakin where should i add it

Comment: You can use `<style>` tag or inline css `style="display: flex"` to the form

Comment: @ArRakin would you please provide code...i cant figure out how to add the code you mentioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it by doing the following:

adding an `id` to the input
<input id="pesticide1Dose"

and assign the following css code to the `id` as follows:

```
pesticide1Dose{
position: absolute;
bottom: 10;
right:0px;
left: 150px;
top: 70px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but you try this:

```html
<div class="modal-body">
            <form #form="ngForm" class="clr-form  clr-form-horizontal" autocomplete="off" style="display: flex">
                <clr-toggle-wrapper>
                <input  type="checkbox" clrCheckbox  (change)="toggleSelectPesticide1()"  [(checked)]="pesticide1Selected"/>
                <label >
                    {{ "SITE.GET_LIDAR" | translate }} 
                </label>
                </clr-toggle-wrapper>
                <clr-input-container>
                    <input
                    required
                    maxlength="25" 
                    clrInput
                    type="text"
                    name="name2"
                    [(ngModel)]=iPesticidesDosesPasser.dose1
                    #name2="ngModel"
                />
            </clr-input-container>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: please see the image in update section above

Comment: Horrible! You might try `clr-toggle-wrapper, clr-input-container { display: inline-block; }`

Answer (score 1):

you can add this class to form:

```
.form-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: start;
  align-items: center; /* to center your items vertically*/
}
```

your form would be like this

```
<form #form="ngForm" class="clr-form  clr-form-horizontal form-wrapper" autocomplete="off">
 /* content here*/
</form>
```

Comment: now i got the alignment as shown in the screen shot in update section above

Comment: try to inspect element the label and text input. maybe it has something to do with the padding or the margin. your can play around on the inspect element. you can even off the align items to check the display scenario

Comment: maybe try to comment out the `align-items: center`